# Python adding lists into a single list with only elements

Tags: python, list

Sorry for the awkward title but I'll explain better here;

In the function below;

```
def returnList():
  list = []
  for i in xrange(4):
    list.append(i)

  return list
```

It returns the list [0,1,2,3]. In another function;

```
def returnAllLists():
  totalList = []
  for i in xrange(4):
    totalList.append(returnList())

  return totalList
```

As expected it turns a result like

```
[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

. The tricky part is that I need the result

```
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

. I can of course easily assign the result of returnAllList to another list **and go for two loops and insert the elements individually into another list** however I think a more efficient way could be done since my method has an **O(N^2)** complexity just for assigning same values in a different way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `extend()` in place of `append()`:

```
 totalList.extend(returnList())
```

Does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great and simple answer

Comment: Or even `totalList += returnList()`

Answer (score 0):

From the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def flatten(listOfLists):
    "Flatten one level of nesting"
    return chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)
```

That's of course assuming you can't just change `append()` to `extend()`.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
In [17]: lis=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]

In [18]: sum(lis,[])
Out[18]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     python 3.2

    a=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]        


    res=[i for v in a for i in v]


    another method:
    list(i.chain(*a))
```